How to upgrade the link library for conda/miniconda?
Inside the miniconda/lib, the output of ll | grep libstdc++ is:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zhongpu zhongpu       19 Apr  7 15:45 libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zhongpu zhongpu       19 Apr  7 15:45 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29
-rwxrwxr-x  3 zhongpu zhongpu 17981480 Jun  1  2022 libstdc++.so.6.0.29

How can I update this lib? I tried conda update --all, but it didn't work.
